# How can I map the user of Wirecloud with the user of my own mysql database?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Since I am making an android application that has its own mysql database in my server, how can I map the user of wirecloud with the user of my own database? The point of this is to recognize which user is consuming a widget deployed on the wirecloud.

I suppose that Wirecloud uses mongo db?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for mapping the users of WireCloud with the ones of you own database is the use of a single authentication source.

WireCloud is based on Django so you can use any of the method supported by it for customising the authentication. This include the use of third-party modules (e.g. `django-auth-ldap` for authenticating using a LDAP server) and the use of the integration with the FIWARE IdM provided by WireCloud.

It's technically possible to make WireCloud use your database directly, but I don't recommend you to do that because will be a pain to maintain such integration. In my opinion, the best options are migrating your app for using the FIWARE IdM or creating a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) for authenticating users using your database.